# divide columns vertically by max value in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a following table:

| id | summary | summary_len | apple | book | computer |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | .... | 210 | 2 | 1 | 0 |
| 2 | ... | 120 | 3 | 0 | 1 |
| 3 | ... | 50 | 2 | 2 | 1 |

summary is basically some sort of description, summary_len <- the length of those descriptions and the rest - apple/book/computer and the keywords and the values presented in the table - those are the occurrences in each description.

I need to normalize this table, in a way to find max value - PER COLUMN (vertically) and then divide by this value, so the output will be as below (I put it in a format 2/3 - just to emphasis max value per column):

| id | summary | summary_len | apple | book | computer |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | .... | 210 | 2/3 | 1/2 | 0/1 |
| 2 | ... | 120 | 3/3 | 0/2 | 1/1 |
| 3 | ... | 50 | 2/3 | 2/2 | 1/1 |

My problem here is that I don't have to find max in each columns - only for those keywords, which I am checking the occurrences for. I stored them in a list and got max value per column:

```
max_per_col = df_freq[keywords].max()
max_per_col
```

this is how it looks (with the original data):
[image]

Could you help me apply it "back" to the former dataframe and divide vertically each column by the max value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can divide only filtered columns by maximal values:

```
keywords = ['apple','book','computer']

df_freq[keywords] /= df_freq[keywords].max()

#working like
#df_freq[keywords] = df_freq[keywords] / df_freq[keywords].max()
print (df_freq)
   id  summary_len     apple  book  computer
0   1          210  0.666667   0.5       0.0
1   2          120  1.000000   0.0       1.0
2   3           50  0.666667   1.0       1.0
```